# Position of the Cancel and Save Buttons on a iPhone

Tags: usability, navigation, buttons, controls

I'm skeptical where to put the Cancel and the Save Buttons in an iOS-app:

Cancel on the left side and Save on right side or vice versa?

[image]

[image]

I think the iOS Human Interface GuidelinesBeta of Apple says nothing about this...

Any help/opinion is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking Apple is the opposite of Windows. The reasons for this go back a long way, and it's Windows that didn't think about it, they simply wanted to do it the opposite to the Mac.

I say this because it's useful to understand that some initial thought went into the order of affirming an action, or escaping from it.

Apple's designers decided we think in terms of the right side being to move forward in activity, so everything on the right is an affirmative action, a doing of something. Left is escaping, cancelling, etc... going backwards.

Having said that, for saving and cancelling a save action, generally speaking, you should be using a popover, either left/right:

[image]

Or you can do the more modern way, vertical, with a separation for Cancel:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that statement @Confused, help me a lot! And this is the way, i´d gone so far...

Comment: You're very welcome! If you have time, I can't strongly enough recommend reading and watching the early thoughts of Alan Kay on UI design.

Comment: where can i find them?